# Bayesian search tensorflow model zoo custom dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

It's possible to hyperparamether tuning in tensorflow object detection model zoo custom dataset with bayesian search in range opimizer, learning_rate, and batch size?

I can't find about tensorflow model zoo hyperparamether custom dataset with hyperparamether tuning with bayesian search